# How to display an image onto website using Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET, I am having trouble displaying an image on the frontend of the website through the HTML code. I am trying to display an image from my computer using the file path in the HTML code and it still will not work. Please help.

I have been trying  but it will not work.

Comment: could you share what you have done so far and any errors you've received? that would make it easier for others to help you

Comment: <img src="Users/adrianavelasco/Desktop/me.jpg" /> I checked a million times if my file path was correct and it is. I'm also using a mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: When I inspect the webpage it tells me that my image  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is that the full file path? It looks like Windows and they usually start with the disk drive letter, e.g. C:/Users/...

Comment: Move/copy the image into the project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET - Image is not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324801/asp-net-image-is-not-showing-up)