# Images aren't showing in gridtable

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio

I can't see the image files I included in my asp.net page. The images are put into the linked access database table first, and I also included the images into the same folder as my web application.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" CellPadding="5" Font-Names="Arial">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="Product ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" HeaderText="Product Price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QtyInStock" HeaderText="Quantity in stock" />
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ProductImage" HeaderText="Image">
                    <ControlStyle BorderStyle="Groove" Height="260px" Width="300px" />
                </asp:ImageField>
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

The product image field is where the images should be.

[image]

Comment: ...Double check that you can directly open the image from the path, then double check you can write the path to a label in the webpage using the ProductImage field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET - Image is not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324801/asp-net-image-is-not-showing-up)